# Routing for Particular Action Adds 'Home' In Front of Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I'm having an odd issue with routing in a basic ASP/MVC project.

I have a bunch of nav items setup:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("index", "home")">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("fire", "home")">Fire</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("law-enforcement", "home")">Law Enforcement</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("forensics", "home")">Forensics</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("reconstruction", "home")">Reconstruction</a></li>
```

They all work fine, except for the third one, labeled `law-enforcement`.

When I mouse over this item, the URL is: `http://localhost:54003/home/law-enforcement`

When I mouse over any other item, the URl is: `http://localhost:54003/fire`

My Controller setup is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("~/fire")]
public ActionResult Fire()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("~/law-enforcement")]
public ActionResult Law()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("~/forensics")]
public ActionResult Forensics()
{
    return View();
}

[Route("~/reconstruction")]
public ActionResult Reconstruction()
{
    return View();
}
```

And my route config is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}
```

When I go to the route the URL specifies, ASP responds with a 404 page not found (as it should). If I go to the route that I know it should be, such as `localhost/law-enforcement` then the correct View is rendered.

Any ideas why ASP is routing this one particular action incorrectly?

Comment: Pretty sure I've figured it out, and it was an ignorance issue. The Razor `Url.Action(...)` cannot refer to the route defined by the `[RouteAttribute]` on the controller action; instead it needs to refer to the action's name. So changing by Razor to refer to `@Url.Action("law", "home")` instead of `law-enforcement` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your url mapping in either of 2 ways as below:

One way is to decorate your `actionresult` with attribute as below:

```
// eg: /home/show-options
[Route("law-enforcement")] //Remove ~
public ActionResult Law() 
{
    return View();
}
```

As per **[docs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)**

otherwise

Just add one more configuration in `Route.config` file

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecialRoute", "{controller}/{action}-{name}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "law-enforcement", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
 );
```

**[Source](http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2013/08/21/Customizing-Routes-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)**

Comment: Marking this as answer, although it doesn't specifically answer the question. For anyone else who is experiencing this, please see my answer. It seems you cannot refer to an action by its Route attribute, but must instead use the action name.

Comment: @mariocatch I feel its possible as per docs I mentioned. May be the scenario is different in your case.. Not sure though!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Razor `Url.Action(...)` cannot refer to the route defined by the `[RouteAttribute]` on the controller action; instead it needs to refer to the action's name. So changing my Razor syntax to refer to `@Url.Action("law", "home")` instead of `@Url.Action("law-enforcement", "home")` solved the issue.